# Can I change the colour of the iPhone 5 letterbox (the black bars at the top and bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-5

I have an app that I can't update for the new size of the iPhone 5- basically it's built around the asset sizes I have, and there's no way to get updated assets.  The app still works fine, but it has a solid white background, and the letterbox (the black bars at the top and bottom) is black, which is really ugly.

Is there any way to set the color of the letterbox to white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could just have google searched it. "You cant!". But there is a workaround. All you have to do is just add a "Default-568h@2x.png" file. You app will fill the display. All you have to do now is just add a white graphic on top and bottom if the device is iPhone5.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that :) But, you could resubmit your app without using updated assets and support iPhone 5 screen. To achieve that, 1) you have to add iPhone 5 launch screen. 2) make your view and subviews resizable so that they appear on their places (No need to create separate nibs) 3) test with iPhone 5 (iPhone 5 simulator), and you are good to go ;) Good Luck!